# dataweave fetch first char from array elements

Tags: dataweave

I am trying to see if any Types.Flag starts with 'X', if true, I need to set 'subscribed' to true.

Input:

```
{
    "Subscribers": [{
            "PhoneNumber": "9876543210",
            "Types": [{
                    "Name": "abcd",
                    "Flag": "WIR"
                },
                {
                    "FilterName": "efg",
                    "Flag": "XNJ"
                },
                {
                    "FilterName": "hijk",
                    "Flag": "YIR"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "PhoneNumber": "9823456789",
            "Types": [{
                "FilterName": "lmn",
                "Flag": "MST"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected output

```
{
  "subscriberList": [
    {
      "phoneNumber": "2012020004",
      "subscribed": true
    },
    {
      "phoneNumber": "2234567890",
      "subscribed": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Could you please suggest on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

import some from dw::core::Arrays

var data = {
    "Subscribers": [{
            "PhoneNumber": "9876543210",
            "Types": [{
                    "Name": "abcd",
                    "Flag": "WIR"
                },
                {
                    "FilterName": "efg",
                    "Flag": "XNJ"
                },
                {
                    "FilterName": "hijk",
                    "Flag": "YIR"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "PhoneNumber": "9823456789",
            "Types": [{
                "FilterName": "lmn",
                "Flag": "MST"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
---
subscriberList: data.Subscribers map {
    phoneNumber: $.PhoneNumber,
    subscribed: $.Types.*Flag some (e) -> e startsWith "X"
}
```

Here's the documentation of the functions I made use of:

- [map](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-map)
- [some](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-arrays-functions-some)
- [startsWith](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-startswith)
- [.* selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-selectors)